# How to make a CASE WHEN THEN from int to varchar?

Tags: sql

Im trying to make a CASE that changes a INT to a VARCHAR.

```
UPDATE puntentotaal SET Leeftijdhoofdkostwinner = 
(CASE
    WHEN Punten1  22 THEN 35 jaar en jonger
    WHEN Punten1  29 THEN 36 t/m 50 jaar
    WHEN Punten1  39 THEN 51 jaar en ouder
END)
```

Why is this code not working?

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need quotation marks. Also, your original case statement can be improved a bit:

```
UPDATE puntentotaal SET Leeftijdhoofdkostwinner = 
(CASE Punten1 
    WHEN 22 THEN '35 jaar en jonger'
    WHEN 29 THEN '36 t/m 50 jaar'
    WHEN 39 THEN '51 jaar en ouder'
    ELSE '' -- You might want to set some sort of value for this; up to you though
END)
```

Comment: @JW another mistake in the original query that I didn't catch at first. Fixed.

Comment: for faster performance, add `WHERE` clause, eg `...WHERE Punten1 IN (22,29,39)`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be: ?

```
UPDATE puntentotaal SET Leeftijdhoofdkostwinner = 
(CASE
    WHEN Punten1  22 THEN '35 jaar en jonger'
    WHEN Punten1  29 THEN '36 t/m 50 jaar'
    WHEN Punten1  39 THEN '51 jaar en ouder'
END)
```